# Laravel: FatalErrorException (syntax error, unexpected '->')

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in Laravel. Can anyone help?

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public function filterMessages($messages)
{
    $collection = collect(Message::all());

    $keys = [];
    foreach ($messages as $m) {
        $keys[] = $m->id;
    }

    return ($collection->whereNotIn('id', $keys))->all();
}
```

Comment: Which one is line `324` of `EloquentCampaignRepository.php`?

Comment: return ($collection->whereNotIn('id', $keys))->all();

Comment: to fix your error do this return ($collection->whereNotIn('id', $keys)->all());

Comment: `Message::all()` returns a collection, why are you calling `collect` again?

Comment: still new in using laravel. appreciate all the feedback.. would let you know if I would solve the issues. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to do this:

```
public function filterMessages($messages) { 
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($messages as $m) {
        $keys[] = $m->id;
    }

    return Message::whereNotIn('id', $keys)->get();
}
```

Comment: Declaration of QRV\Campaign\Repositories\Eloquent\EloquentCampaignRepository::updateMessageSequence() must be compatible with QRV\Campaign\Repositories\CampaignRepositoryInterface::updateMessageSequence(QRV\Campaign\Entities\Campaign $campaign, QRV\Campaign\Repositories\int $messageId, array $data)

Answer (score 0):

you have placed your closing parenthesis in the wrong place

```
return ($collection->whereNotIn('id', $keys))->all();
```

that would give you an error .. also all() function will return it all , so it should be

```
return ($collection->whereNotIn('id', $keys)->get());
```

Comment: THANKS. It sold the problem but it resulted to another issue

Comment: Declaration of QRV\Campaign\Repositories\Eloquent\EloquentCampaignRepository::updateMessageSequence() must be compatible with QRV\Campaign\Repositories\CampaignRepositoryInterface::updateMessageSequence(QRV\Campaign\Entities\Campaign $campaign, QRV\Campaign\Repositories\int $messageId, array $data)

Comment: public function updateMessageSequence(Campaign $campaign, int $messageId, array $data)
    {
        $campaign->messages()->updateExistingPivot($messageId, $data);
    }

Comment: well that's another question or issue to solve .. so i think it's better to ask another question so it will not affect the answers already given ..